# Formula Used by Microsoft to Calculate Memory Usage % in Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

Haven't been able to find an answer for this question.  Here is some background.

I am on W7 64 Pro, and I can see the breakdown in Resource Monitor, but, when I add up the totals of the columns, I cannot no matter what I do come up with the % number calculated by MS, which seems unreliable in itself.  I say this because, I have a system that had a runaway RAM problem, and the process eventually made the system unusable, but Task Manager said the system was at 65% usage capacity, while the error claimed that there was no available memory.  For the record, this system has always had a "RAM creep" issue, even before the runaway issue.

OK, this brings me to the 65% RAM usage system failures.  I could see that the onboard graphics could have a lock on 2 GB, which I think is correct for this system.  I was using the board/processor graphics at the time.  If onboard graphics do reserve memory, nowhere is this shown as part of any process, however, and it seems that it should show up in Resource Monitor as "Hardware Reserved".  Also, on the System Properties windows and in System Information, the system is shown as having 8 GB, not 6 or 7.5, etc.  At any rate, info is hard to come by for an HP 6200 Pro with Intel 2000 graphics, so I'm not sure how the graphics are managed.  Graphics processing for the onboard graphics is handled in the processor with this i5 processor (i5-2400).  Well, maybe graphics allocation (reserved memory) is why the system tapped out of memory at 65%, idk.  Ultimately, I did manage to find the runaway process, which was an HWiNFO drive monitor, and the runaway usage stopped.  However, usage is still too high.  The system has 8 GB, and, even after a couple of months of stabilizing and after adding a dedicated graphics card (HD 4550), memory idles at about 46%.  This is compared to other systems I have that idle at 25-35%.  I can't say, but the creeping aspect of the memory problem has at least slowed.  It's hard to tell, because it does seem to be idling at a higher and higher %, but maybe it will stop, and it's a very slow creeping process.

But this is what I really would like to know.  No matter how I add the columns in Task Manager using a spreadsheet, I cannot come up with the total % MS shows in TM.  This is of course what is also used by monitoring software, so I assume there is something to the number.  But how does MS calculate the number.

For the record, even if I add working set and private ws together, I still come up far short of what MS says the system is using.  If I add commit to the total I go over.  Again, I can see in Resource Monitor what MS says is in use, so please don't bring that up.  It's just that it's nowhere that I can find defined or published what exactly MS means by "In Use".

Answer (score 0):

Adding up memory usage columns will never equal total usage. There are some significant users of memory that are not processes. These include the Non paged pool, the resident portion of the Paged pool, and the file cache. There some others but they are usually quite small.

Oddly enough the file cache is not included in the "Cached" value shown in Task Manager. It is included in the in use RAM but is not identified in any way. It is available in Performance Monitor and some other utilities. The file cache can easily be 500 MB or higher. Much higher in some cases.

Memory usage in any modern OS is far too complex to be calculated by simply adding up a column of numbers.

The memory usage percent calculation is simple:
In use memory / total memory * 100.